# Creating a loop within an assembly macro - IAR ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, iar, cortex-m

I am trying to create a loop within an IAR Arm assembly macro but cannot figure out how to make local labels, if the macro is called more than once I get duplicate label error from the assembler. My code is as follows:

```
myMacro MACRO
     MOV R1, #0
label:  enter code here
     do some stuff here
     ADD R1, R1, #1         
     CMP R1, #10
     BLE label
     ENDM
```

Comment: http://vision.gel.ulaval.ca/~jflalonde/cours/1001/h15/docs/IAR_ref.pdf page "60" in print (74/137 shows pdf viewer), looks like you should use directive `LOCAL` to create local symbol. On page "65" in print there's example of `LOCAL loop` ahead of `loop:` label.

Comment: Thanks. I already has this document open but completely missed it. The solution was much simpler than I was looking for.

Comment: Many assemblers also support [numeric local labels](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32341112/3156750) for precisely this sort of thing - I don't know about IAR, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved below:

```
myMacro MACRO
         LOCAL label
         MOV R1, #0
    label:  enter code here
         do some stuff here
         ADD R1, R1, #1         
         CMP R1, #10
         BLE label
         ENDM
```