# Anonymous local labels (@@): Which assemblers support multi-step references such as @FF (second-next @@)?

Tags: assembly, label, nasm, masm, fasm

In some x86 assembler dialects, one can place anonymous local labels using `@@:` and refer to them in jumps like `jmp @F` where @F refers to "next @@" and @B refers to "previous @@".

Here's a description from Microsoft I found while searching the web: [Q33067: Anonymous Labels for Jump Instructions](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/033/Q33067/)

I implemented support for anonymous local labels in NASM using its preprocessor's macro facilities, [in my macro collection](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/lmacros/file/be2ef8df4374/lmacros2.mac#l942). All the way back to [the first implementation on 2011-08-08](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/lmacros/rev/eca20249379f) I had support for multi-step references. That is, `jmp @FF` refers to the second-next @@.

Today I got curious about the differences, if any, to MASM's handling of anonymous local labels. However, I couldn't find anything explicitly stating that multi-step references are supported by MASM. The link I gave only describes @F and @B. It doesn't specifically state anything to the effect that multi-step references are *not* supported either, though.

The only occurrence of @FF that I found on the web is [in this FASM forum thread](https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=4716&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0) which discusses the possibility of adding multi-step @@ references. This seems to imply that, at least prior to this thread, FASM only supported single-step @@ references.

My question is, which assemblers do support multi-step references? Specifically, do MASM and TASM support them?

If you care for the context, I never use @B4 or @F4 except [in the macro collection's tests](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/lmacros/file/be2ef8df4374/tests/000.asm) and have as yet used @B3 or @F3 three times:

- [First @FFF](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/4eea3552e7c5/source/uu.asm#l1289),
- the nearby [@BBB](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/4eea3552e7c5/source/uu.asm#l1323),
- and [second @FFF](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/4eea3552e7c5/source/symbols.asm#l1057)

@B2 and @F2 are fairly common in my sources though.

Comment: I would take the lack of documentation of a feature to mean that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Another source, jump to "Local Code Labels": http://bytepointer.com/masm/ml6.0b_quickhelp.htm Likewise only mentions @F and @B.

Comment: Given that anonymous labels date back to an idea by Knuth and Knuth didn't have “multi-step references,” I suppose there won't be many.  If you need so many labels that 0–9 won't cut it, try using a normal label instead.

Answer (score 2):

GAS numbered local labels ([`as` manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html)) are the same concept as MASM's `@@`: can be defined multiple times, `f` or `b` suffix to choose the closest one in that direction.

But instead of only `@@`, you have your choice of any number as the label name (typically single-digit), basically solving the same problem of being able to use labels in macros without hitting multiple-definition problems, and refer to a label that's not the immediately previous or next local label.

```
    jmp 3f
1:  nop
2:  jmp 4f
3:  jmp 1b
4:
```

See also [ARM Assembly Local Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341112/arm-assembly-local-labels) for other examples.

---

NASM doesn't natively have either of these.  `.name` labels are scoped to the previous non-dot label name, but for use in a macro it has special syntax for [macro-local labels](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.3.2) like `%%foo:`.

Comment: I did wonder whether eg `1ff` would be valid, but your manual link makes it explicit that it isn't: "[...] you can only refer to the most recently defined local label of that number (for a backwards reference) or the next definition of a specific local label for a forward reference."

Answer (score 1):

Instead of leading *at-sign* **@** €ASM uses leading *fullstop* **.** to specify localness of the label. Arbitrary number of different local labels can be defined and refered in one namespace block (PROC..ENDP) and they also can be refered from other blocks when the local label is concatenated with the name of its block. 
The number of steps (nesting depth) is not limited then, see https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#Namespace

Comment: That's exactly like NASM, except for being scoped to PROC/ENDP instead of just the most recent non-dot label.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, but there's another difference: NASM's namespaces cannot be nested, and you cannot jump to a local label in another namespace scope in NASM.

Comment: You can't nest in NASM, but the access-from-outside mechanism is *identical*.  After `foo: resb 100` ; `.size equ $ - foo`, you can elsewhere in the program `mov eax, foo.size`.  It's the same concat mechanism you describe, also giving names like `func.loop` in a debugger for a function with a `.loop` local label.