# Go back after jump

Tags: if-statement, assembly, label, x86-64, nasm

I have this code, I need check `RCX` register three times. I made a few lines of code (24-34 lines). In the first time (first `jz`), I move to `true:` label, but after I can't go back and check it the second time (28-30 lines). My program just finish everytime after the first `jz`. How can I go back and check it three time?

```
default REL
extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteFile
extern ExitProcess


section .data
    true_msg db 'Yes', 0

    true_msg_len equ $-true_msg

section .text
    global _main

_main:
    and rsp, -10h
    sub rsp, 020h

    mov rcx, -0Bh
    call GetStdHandle

    ;jmp true

    mov rcx, 2
    cmp rcx, 2
    jz true

    mov rcx, 0
    cmp rcx, 0
    jz true
    
    mov rcx, 1
    cmp rcx, 0
    jz true

;----------------
    add rsp, 28h                            ; Restore Stack Pointer
;----------------
    mov rcx, 0                              ; RCX - first argument.
    call ExitProcess
;----------------
    xor rax, rax
    ret

true:
    mov rcx, rax
    mov rdx, true_msg
    mov r8, true_msg_len
    xor r9, r9
    push r9
    sub rsp, 20h
    call WriteFile
```

I want to get something like:

```
if(...){
   ...
}

if(...){
   ...
}

if(...){
   ...
}
```

I need every condition to be checked.

Comment: Why do you jump to `true` in each of those cases? Is it always the same code that's supposed to be executed? If so, why isn't it written as `if (cond1 || cond2 || cond3) { ... }` instead?

Comment: If it's _not_ always the same code that's supposed to be executed, then the obvious solution would be to do something like `jnz @F` followed by the code that should be executed (or a `call` to a function that contains that code) followed by `@@:`. If you prefer named labels over anonymous ones, that's fine.

Comment: @Michael: This looks like NASM source. NASM does not have `@@` style labels built in. (However, [my macro collection](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/lmacros/file/ede277bd4d21/lmacros2.mac#l947) can add support for `@@`, including [multi-step references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338385/anonymous-local-labels-which-assemblers-support-multi-step-references-such).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a missunderstanding on how to execute this. In a simple way:

```
if (test) {
   //block1
}
if (test2) {
   //block2
}
if(test3) {
   //block3
}
```

(Pay attention on where those block1, block2 and block3 will appear in my next exemple)

Each if needs to test (the test into parenthesys) and then either go and execute the possibility it is true and the possibility it is not true.
So it would be something like this:

```
;first if, start by comparing:
   mov rcx, 2
   cmp rcx, 2
   jnz false1 ;jumps for the false possibility of the first if

   ;here you type what will happen when the first if is executed (block1)

false1: ;here the first if is finnished, this label is the jump for not executing that first if

   ;then now you execute the second if:

   ;first compare:
   mov rcx, 0
   cmp rcx, 0
   jnz false2 ;jumps for not executing the if block

   ;here is block2

false2:

   ;now here the last if, just like the last two:

   mov rcx, 1
   cmp rcx, 0
   jnz false3

   ;here block3

false3:
   ;here is the rest of your code after those ifs
```

I changed the logic for jumping in false possibility instead of true (as you did) because in cases where there is no "else" block, it makes the code smaller than the way you did.

Comment: Yes, you often want to jump over a block when if block shouldn't be executed.  To keep the same condition as the code in the question, you should be using the opposite condition `jnz` (or more idiomatically after `cmp`, `jne`).  i.e. turn `if(test) stuff;` it into `if(!test) goto after_stuff;`.   So the if body executes when `2 == 2`.

Comment: that's right, I forgot to turn the jz into a jnz, I edited the answer with the correct jump